# Can't render dateTime

Tags: twig, symfony4

I make an entity "comment" with fields id, pseudo, email, comment and published_at.

My entity :

```php
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
*/
private $published_at;
    
public function __construct()
{
    $this->published_at= new \DateTime();
}

public function getPublishedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->published_at;
}

public function setPublishedAt(\DateTime $published_at): self
{
    $this->published_at = $published_at;

    return $this;
}
```

My migration:

```php
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE comment (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, pseudo VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, comment LONGTEXT NOT NULL, published_at DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
}
```

I make a controller :

```php
$comments = $commentRepo->findBy([], ['published_at' => 'desc']);
//        dd($comments);
return $this->render('comment/comments.html.twig', [
    'commentForm' => $form->createView(),
    'comments' => $comments,
]);
```

My render twig :

```html
 <div>
                {% for comment in comments %}
                    <div class="text-light">
                        {{ comment.pseudo }}
                        {{ comment.published_at|date('d/m/Y H:i:s')}}
                        {{ comment.comment | raw }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

For `{{comment.pseudo}}` and `{{comment.comment}}` display well
But for `{{comment.published_at}}` I have this error :

> Neither the property "published_at" nor one of the methods "published_at()", "getpublished_at()"/"ispublished_at()"/"haspublished_at()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Comment".

Comment: Your getter is `getPublishedAt`, so it should be `{{ comment.publishedAt|date('d/m/Y H:i:s')}}`

Comment: that's it, a big thank you